# python subprocess and empty strings

Tags: python, subprocess, string

I am trying to use the .subprocess.check_output() function to issue commands to a crypto-coin wallet (like bitcoin, but not). Some of the commands work great, but one does not return the correct results. I suspect the use of an empty string ("") is the problem, but need help finding a solution.

I am using Python 2.7 on a Raspberry Pi B+.
My code is:

```
import subprocess
command = 'rimbitd getaddressesbyaccount ""'
print "The command is: ", command
results = subprocess.check_output(command.split())
print "The Results are: ", results
```

My output is:

```
pi@Pi ~ $ python Demo2.py
The command is:  rimbitd getaddressesbyaccount ""
The Results are:  [
]
```

Obviously the results are an empty set of brackets. But, if I use the exact same command directly (at the $ prompt) by copying/pasting the rimbitd getaddressesbyaccount "" from the output (i.e. "The command is: ...") then I get the following (correct) output:

```
pi@Pi ~ $ rimbitd getaddressesbyaccount ""
[
    "RPSXNdNu4TsfyrytMSFz5RvxeSqrRyQMg6",
    "RGyFKcrYR6NGr82Gqsjamj9DgEj7ZBUyfM",
    "RLwQ9XGPesV35KK84oUupUh62tNori9Ahe",
    "RQ2HRzX3U9NGP14dLAM7TPagNPhYKbTaVM",
    "RNvR2vvaWmUnij88tTiGTXFLgZU1daKVvz"
]
pi@Pi ~ $
```

Other commands work as described (sending coins, checking the balance, etc.). I just can't get this one to work and the only difference is that the non-working command needs to send an empty string. I have tried using n = "" and then concatenating: commands + n (no joy). I have tried using:

```
results = subprocess.check_output("rimbitd", "getaddressesbyaccount", " \"\"").
```

I have tried using a number of methods to get the empty string through, but none have worked.

Comment: Please disregard/delete. I found the solution by the "shotgun" method. It appears the .split() function doesn't like the empty string. Using "subprocess.check_output(["rimbitd", "getaddressesbyaccount", ""]) worked fine.

Comment: `.split()` works as expected. It is your expectations that are incorrect. The key insight is that `subprocess` module does *not* invoke the shell by default and it is the shell that parses the command line into an argument list on POSIX systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting `'rimbitd getaddressesbyaccount ""'` doesn't give you an empty third parameter; it gives you a parameter consisting of two quotes:

```
>>> 'rimbitd getaddressesbyaccount ""'.split()
['rimbitd', 'getaddressesbyaccount', '""']
```

You want to use

```
['rimbitd', 'getaddressesbyaccount', '']
```

for this if the last parameter needs to be empty (for which you would use a pair of double quotes when invoked from the shell prompt).

As J.F.Sebastian indicated, you can also use the `shlex` module:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('rimbitd getaddressesbyaccount ""')
['rimbitd', 'getaddressesbyaccount', '']
```

`subprocess.check_output()` by default doesn't run the commands in a shell. You could also have used your original `.split()` and provide `check_output()` with the `shell=True` keyword argument.

Comment: `shlex.split()` works in this case. You could mention that the shell removes quotes in the first case and `subprocess` does not use the shell by default.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks incorporated that with credits.

Comment: [do not use a list argument and `shell=True` together](http://bugs.python.org/issue21347), it is an error on POSIX systems in most cases.